# How to properly validate an extension of an XML schema?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm working on an extension to the SCTE-224 standard XML schema (http://www.scte.org/schemas/224/2015/SCTE224.xsd). The spec allows for extension of the standard by including elements of any other namespace within the `Metadata` element:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Metadata">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" namespace="##other"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I've defined some top-level elements in my own namespace that should go inside the SCTE-224 standard elements. For example, the `bam:Program` element:

```
<Media id="/media/12345" description="A standard SCTE-224 Media element.">
  <Metadata>
    <bam:Program>
      ... Additional bam-namespaced elements
    </bam:Program>
  </Metadata>
</Media>
```

My goal is to be able to have my own XSD that defines the schema for our extended spec, taking into account both the elements from the standard and the `bam:` elements. Below is a first stab at the extended elements, but I can't figure out how to specify that the `bam:Program` element must appear inside `Media/Metadata`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://specs.bamgrid.com" targetNamespace="http://specs.bamgrid.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="Genres">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Genre">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Program">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ProgramDetails" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ProgramDetail" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="TitleBrief" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="TitleSort" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="DescriptionBrief" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="language" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="[a-z][a-z]"/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ProgramType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Images" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Image" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute ref="xlink:href" use="required"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="Genres" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="contentSource" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for describing this extended schema?

Comment: Why do you want to specify the required parent element? I don't think it's possible, but don't even see a reason.

Comment: @daniu - Because `<Media>` elements must have a `<bam:Program>` element inside their `<Metadata>` to be valid in our system.

Comment: I think what you need to do is to add an extended `Media` element which requires a `Program` child, and then use that for validation; that would be in another namespace than `Media`, but you could use xslt to transform the xml document into the new namespace and validate that.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for the ##other namespace, the reason for our failure.

First, create your handler by implementing `ValidationEventHandler` interface.

```
package com.packagename.handler;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * @author <tomer.madmon@imaginecommunications.com>
 *
 */
public class SCTE224Handler implements ValidationEventHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SCTE224Handler.class);
    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        if(event.getMessage().contains("##other")){ // means ##other namespace like metadata in SCTE224 
            logger.warn(event.toString());
            return true;    
        }
        logger.error(event.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, set the handler and schema and it will work.

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
SCTE224Handler validatorHandler = new SCTE224Handler();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(validatorHandler);
```